# how to show multi array data in my console log

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

i am new in angularjs and mongodb please check below data and code.. i want to show data in console log but its show undefined  i don't know why, i was try many times but does not success please guys help me i am very thankful to you please check below code

```
var current_schedules = this.current.schedule;
if (angular.isArray(current_schedules)) {
  for (var j = 0; j < current_schedules.length; j++) {
    console.log(current_schedules[j].length);
    for (var i = 0; i < current_schedules[j].length; i++) {
      console.log(current_schedules[j][i].title);
    }
  }
}

//MOngodb Data
"schedule" : [ 
  [ 
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("58f76aa9be4d311a78f24f78"),
      "sch_end" : ISODate("2017-04-24T00:00:00.000Z"),
      "sch_start" : ISODate("2017-04-24T00:00:00.000Z"),
      "available" : false,
      "title" : "test3"
    }, 
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("58f76aa9be4d311a78f24f77"),
      "sch_end" : ISODate("2017-04-25T00:00:00.000Z"),
      "sch_start" : ISODate("2017-04-25T00:00:00.000Z"),
      "available" : false,
      "title" : "test4"
    }, 
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("58f76aa9be4d311a78f24f76"),
      "sch_end" : ISODate("2017-04-27T00:00:00.000Z"),
      "sch_start" : ISODate("2017-04-27T00:00:00.000Z"),
      "available" : false,
      "title" : "test6"
    }
  ], 
  [ 
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("58f76aa9be4d311a78f24f78"),
      "sch_end" : ISODate("2017-04-24T00:00:00.000Z"),
      "sch_start" : ISODate("2017-04-24T00:00:00.000Z"),
      "available" : false,
      "title" : "test9"
    }, 
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("58f76aa9be4d311a78f24f77"),
      "sch_end" : ISODate("2017-04-25T00:00:00.000Z"),
      "sch_start" : ISODate("2017-04-25T00:00:00.000Z"),
      "available" : false,
      "title" : "test10"
    }, 
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("58f76aa9be4d311a78f24f76"),
      "sch_end" : ISODate("2017-04-27T00:00:00.000Z"),
      "sch_start" : ISODate("2017-04-27T00:00:00.000Z"),
      "available" : false,
      "title" : "test11"
    }
  ]
]
```

[when i use console.log(current_schedules); its show data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0ux3.jpg)

Comment: what does the console show when current_schedules is logged?

Comment: did u try console.dir(current_schedules[j][i].title); ?

Comment: they show data when i log console.log(current_schedules); show above pic